# On finite $p$ -group of class two with cyclic center

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Does there exist a finite $p$-group of nilpotentcy class $2$ such that

1. $Z(G)$ is not a subgroup of $\Phi(G)$, where $Z(G)$ is center of $G$ and $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$.
2. $G/Z(G)$  is generated by 2 elements.
3. $Z(G)$ is cyclic.

Explanation:

For condition 1 and 2 we can say $D_{8}\times C_{2}.$

For condition 2 and 3 we can say $D_{8}$.

For condition 1 and 3 ?

For condition 1 and 2 and 3?

Thank you

Comment: nilpotency class $2$?

Comment: @JorgeFernández: Yes

Comment: you want all at the same time or seperatly ?

Comment: @mesel: I want all the same time. But the case 1 and 3 is true.

Comment: well, we ca say that $G/\Phi(G)\cong Z_p\times Z_p \times Z_p$ and $G/\Phi(G)Z(G)\cong Z_p\times Z_p$ .

Comment: Thus If there are such group they have at leat $p^4$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The central product of $D_8$ and $C_4$ is such an example. More generally, for arbitrary primes $p$, you can take the central product of an extraspecial group of order $p^3$ with $C_{p^2}$.